# Methods with Parameters in Java

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing

Could someone explain **why** this works.

I have 2 classes in Eclipse.
A Class called "Car" contains the following code..

```
public class Car {
    public void printOut(String variable1){
        System.out.println("Hello " +variable1);
    }
}
```

and another class , which is where my 'main' is, is called "House", the code inside it is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class House {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Car carObject = new Car();

        System.out.println("Enter name here: ");
        String variable2 = input.nextLine();

        carObject.printOut(variable2);
    }
}
```

When I run the code, it works, it writes "Enter name here" and when I type it out, it proceeds to say "Hello "name entered" "

My question is, do 'variable1' and 'variable2' have any relation to eachother, other than that they're both of String class.

because i'm confused as to why the code compiles correctly.

To me, it looks like variable 1 has no correlation to variable2, even though they're both of String class, it doesn't look like they ever interact with one another, and variable1 isn't used in the "House" class at all, yet it still knows to compile whatever I've entered.
It's as if 'variable1' is replaced by 'variable2' and whatever variable2 contains gets printed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method definition in class `Car` is sort of a prototype for when you use it. Have you ever been taught functions in maths with a 'black box'? You put in a number, and get output. So, you enter 3, if the function is f(x) = Xx2, the output will be 6. Before you call the method, var2 is completely different from var1. In the method however, var2 is passed and replaces all var1s you use in the method. Don't worry, I didn't get this either when I started Java

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes complete sense, I just wasn't sure about the 'why' . I knew how it worked just didn't know why. 

Thanks to your, and everyone else's answer, I get it. 

You guys rock.

Comment: No worries, just remember to accept the best answer (hint, hint) :)

Answer (score 3):

They're related only because you are passing `variable2` into your `Car.printOut` method.  Imagine this analogy for a moment: You know how to do math homework on command.  You are an object, called `FacelessVoid` and you have a method called `doHomework`.  `doHomework` takes a single parameter of type `Work`.  In the real world, I would have a box of work, and I would dump the box of work onto your desk.  Whatever I write on the box doesn't matter to you, but the contents of the box get dumped onto your desk, where you can call it whatever you want.

This is exactly what is happening in your code: You have a string called `variable2`, and its contents get "dumped" into `variable1` inside `printOut`.  Of note though is that the string doesn't actually get `dumped` into your method, a reference gets copied.  So it's the same object, it's just called something different.

Answer (score 1):

The reference in variable2 will simply be called copied into variable2. The variable2 is passed as a method argument.
Apart from that there is no relationship. Variable2 is local only to main, variable1 is local only to printOut. 
think of variable1 as a function parameter expecting a value from the calling method. Meaning you could pass any string into printOut.

For example `carObject.printOut("Toyota")`
As you can see I am not passing a variable into printOut but a hard coded string

Answer (score 1):

variable2 is a **reference** to a string somewhere in memory. The value in variable2 is used by Java to find out where the string is. For example:

```
variable2                   memory location 1100
[1100]      ------>         "hello"
```

variable1 is also a reference to a string somewhere in memory. When you call the function, the value in variable2 (in this case 1100) is placed in variable1.

```
variable1                   memory location 1100
[1100]      ------>         "hello"
```

So the function can find the string that variable2 references by using variable1, since the location of the string is contained in both. Or put another way, they both reference the same string.

Answer (score 0):

Variable2 value will be moved to variable1 while calling the method

Answer (score 0):

They are exactly the same as you pass variable2 to the printOut() Method. variable1 is just a name for the parameter of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names from the caller or the callee have no effect. You could have a variable parameter named `orange` and the other one `helicopter` it would do the same. The important thing is that they must have the same type (here `String`).

The content of the caller variable is passed to the method, no matter the name of both of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

`variable1` is not actually a variable, it's a name of the variable that will be passed to the method. You will need this name because you're using it in your method for some operations. So when you pass `variable2`, which now is a variable indeed, you see it in the method under the name of `variable1`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Java parameters are always passed by value. If you however pass an object then its pointing to the original object reference and you can modify the original object.

Answer (score 0):

there is no relataion v1 and v2.
When you call car.printOut() method from Hous class, it pushes v2 to stack as value.
car.printOut() method pop this value to v1 variable from stack. Therefore you can use any name.

Additionally, when you change value of v1 at printOut(), v2 will not change.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given good answers, but just to get your vocabulary right, `variable1` is called a ["formal parameter"](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_actual_and_formal_parameters) whereas `variable2` is the actual parameter, also called as the "argument" passed to the method `printOut`. It would be easier to realize that you are just playing with names when it comes to passing around arguments. At the gut level, it's just playing around with data locations rather than referring stuff by name.